# Send Ajax request upon textarea change/ update

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am looking to create an Ajax request whenever my text area changes, my backend is using PHP and I am not sure what the best way to write the Ajax request and or PHP side to prevent against any abuse, as someone could just start spamming the textarea and that could create a DoS against my site because of all the Ajax requests which in the end access the DB.

I have the JS code to detect whenever a change happens as I am using the Ace code editor, so my code looks like this:

```
codeEditor.getSession().on('change', function(e)
{

});
```

Currently this is what my Ajax script looks like:

```
// Variable to hold request
    var request;

    // Prevent default posting of form - put here to work in case of errors
    event.preventDefault();

    // Abort any pending request
    if (request) {
        request.abort();
    }
    // setup some local variables
    var form = $(this);

    // Serialize the data in the form
    var serializedData = form.serialize();

    // Fire off the request to /form.php
    request = $.ajax({
        url: form.attr("action"),
        type: "post",
        data: serializedData
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called on success
    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
      // This is where I would say "Saved"...
    });

    // Callback handler that will be called on failure
    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
      // Log the error to the console
      console.error("The following error occurred: "+ textStatus, errorThrown);
    });
```

$this is basically the ID of the form got before the Ajax script...

What else could/ can I do to improve this request both front and back end to prevent abuse of spamming the textarea and if there is anything else I should add to this for security? Note: I have already sorted out CSRF protect elsewhere, so that is not an issue here.

Comment: not familar with ace change ... if it fires for all key strokes, pastes, etc you could store locally and only update server periodically and/or when final save is done

Comment: Do you think it would be better to just use a normal save button and post when the user is done?

Comment: depends on use case .... if there is a fear of losing something important can always store drafts in localStorage...and clear that when save is done